# Can Pyspark Use JDBC to Pass Alter Table

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, pyspark, databricks

I would like to pass an alter table command to my PostgreSQL database after I load data from a Databricks notebook using pyspark. I know that I can pass a query using `spark.read.jdbc` but in this case I would like to add a unique constraint once the data has loaded. The purpose is to speed up the data load process into the db by reducing the time to create the unique index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark is a framework for data processing therefore its API mostly developed for read and write operations with data sources. In your case, you have some DDL statements to execute and Spark isn't supposed to perform such operations.

It will better option, to keep DDL operation separate after data processing in spark sql. Here you can add one more PostgreSQL job to perform such operations.

Comment: You rendered this answer as a quote, which indicates that you copied it from somewhere else. If that is the case, please attribute the quote and make sure it is not your whole answer (answers should be written by you, optionally supported by quotes). If this is your own answer, then please don't use the quote block.

Comment: Thanks, that I don't know, I was just using it for formatting.

Comment: Quote blocks are for quotes only.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I will just have to go about this another way then. Databricks connect maybe so I can modularize my process to add the constraints using the pg API.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this exact problem in [Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72384807/rename-a-redshift-sql-table-within-pyspark-databricks). After reviewing the [doc on JDBC connections](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html#write-data-to-jdbc), it looks like you can do something like this:

```
%sql 

ALTER TABLE <jdbcTable> {SOME ACTIONS}
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
  url "jdbc:<databaseServerType>://<jdbcHostname>:<jdbcPort>",
  dbtable "<jdbcDatabase>.atable",
  user "<jdbcUsername>",
  password "<jdbcPassword>"
)
```